# Changing state of Button in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

What i want to do in flutter is when i press button1 it enables button2 and then it disables himself and i want to do the same for button2.

```
bool button1 = true;
bool button2 = false;

void _button1(){
    setState(){
      button1=false;button2=true;
    }
  }
void _button2(){
    setState(){
      button1=true;button2=false;
    }
  }

new MaterialButton(onPressed: button1 ? _button1 :null,child: Text("button1"),color: Colors.greenAccent,),
new MaterialButton(onPressed: button2 ? _button2 :null,child: Text("button2"),color: Colors.greenAccent,),
```

But it's not working for me, because when i press button1 nothing happens.

Comment: you need to call `setState`

Comment: I updated the code and it still not works as i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Works with Single bool Variable :

```
class Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  bool buttonState = true;

  void _buttonChange() {
    setState(() {
      buttonState = !buttonState;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Button State'),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: buttonState ? _buttonChange : null,
              child: Text("button1"),
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: buttonState ? null : _buttonChange,
              child: Text("button2"),
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
            ),
          ],
        )));
  }
}
```

Also In your Code SetState is not Correct:

it Should Be:

```
  bool button1 = true;
  bool button2 = false;

  void _button1() {
    setState(() {
      button1 = false;
      button2 = true;
    });
  }

  void _button2() {
    setState(() {
      button1 = true;
      button2 = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Button State"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: button1 ? _button1 : null,
              child: Text("button1"),
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
            ),
            MaterialButton(
              onPressed: button2 ? _button2 : null,
              child: Text("button2"),
              color: Colors.greenAccent,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me but id don't understand what's the difference between setState(){} and setState((){}) .

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a `bool` variable and check it while displaying the widgets as I have done in my example. Or you can always use `setState` which is safe and always ensures that your widgets get changed. Here is a simple example though

```
bool enable = true;
Scaffold(
    body: Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    enable
        ? MaterialButton(
            child: Text("Button 1"),
            onPressed: () {
              enable = !enable;
            },
          )
        : Container(),
    !(enable)
        ? MaterialButton(
            child: Text("Button 2"),
            onPressed: () {
              enable = !enable;
            })
        : Container()
  ],
)),
```

Comment: It changes the button after hot reload but i want to change it live on app without hot reload.

Comment: Add `setState` in `onPressed`